# Span not responding to overflow-x: hidden

Tags: html, css, css-position, overflow

I am having issues getting the .circle.three span overflow to become hidden. It's preventing me from moving forward with responsiveness and other display issues. I have tried implementing every suggestion I was able to come across with no success.

```css
.landing-page {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #32322C;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  color: rgb(203, 243, 241);
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 20%, #149279);
  position: absolute;
}

.circle.three {
  /* position: absolute; */
  width: 60em;
  height: 60em;
  right: -25%;
  z-index: 0;
}

#three-overflow {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header class="landing-page" id="welcome-section">
  <div class="cover" onclick="closeNav();"></div>
  <svg class="ham hamRotate ham1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="60" onclick="closeNav()">
                <path class="line top"
                    d="m 30,33 h 40 c 0,0 9.044436,-0.654587 9.044436,-8.508902 0,-7.854315 -8.024349,-11.958003 -14.89975,-10.85914 -6.875401,1.098863 -13.637059,4.171617 -13.637059,16.368042 v 40" />
                <path class="line middle" d="m 30,50 h 40" />
                <path class="line bottom"
                    d="m 30,67 h 40 c 12.796276,0 15.357889,-11.717785 15.357889,-26.851538 0,-15.133752 -4.786586,-27.274118 -16.667516,-27.274118 -11.88093,0 -18.499247,6.994427 -18.435284,17.125656 l 0.252538,40" />
            </svg>
  <div class="top_contacts">
    <a href="https://github.com/ZMoberg" id="profile-link" class="top_contacts-link" target="_blank" alt="Github"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/zackmoberg/" id="profile-link" class="top_contacts-link" target="_blank" alt="Linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  </div>

  <!--Navigation bar-->
  <nav id="navbar" class="nav">
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#about_scroll">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#projects-scroll">PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <span class="circle three" id="three-overflow"></span>
  <section class="head_sub">
    <h1 class="title">ZACK MOBERG</h1>
    <p class="title_sub">Web Developer & UI/UX Designer</p>
    <div class="header_nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="title_nav"><a href="#about_scroll" class="left">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li class="title_nav"><a href="#projects-scroll" class="left">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li class="title_nav"><a href="#contact" class="left">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Scroll down animation -->

  <div class="mouse_scroll">
    <a href="#about_scroll">
      <div class="mouse">
        <div class="wheel"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="scroll_arrows">
        <span class="m_scroll_arrows unu"></span>
        <span class="m_scroll_arrows doi"></span>
        <span class="m_scroll_arrows trei"></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

</header>
```

Here's a link to the repo https://github.com/ZMoberg/portfolio

I'm sorry if this is the wrong way to address this issue, I want to abide by proper formatting practices so please feel free to let me know.

Also as I am still learning I welcome any and all feedback on the project as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your span isn't responding to `overflow-x: hidden` because there is nothing overflowing it, since it doesn't have any child element. In fact, the body is being overflowed by the span.

Therefore, you can add `overflow-x: hidden` to body, or if you don't want the circle exceeds your header in the Y axis (principally in smaller screens), add `overflow: hidden` to the header.

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.landing-page {
        height: 100vh;
        width: auto;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #32322C;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        color: rgb(203, 243, 241);
        z-index: 1;
        min-height: 500px;
        display: flex;
    }
    
    
    .circle {
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 20%, #149279);
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    .circle.three {
        /* position: absolute; */
        width: 60em;
        height: 60em;
        right: -25%;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    
    #three-overflow {
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
<header class="landing-page" id="welcome-section">
        <div class="cover" onclick="closeNav();"></div>
        <svg class="ham hamRotate ham1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="60" onclick="closeNav()">
            <path class="line top"
                d="m 30,33 h 40 c 0,0 9.044436,-0.654587 9.044436,-8.508902 0,-7.854315 -8.024349,-11.958003 -14.89975,-10.85914 -6.875401,1.098863 -13.637059,4.171617 -13.637059,16.368042 v 40" />
            <path class="line middle" d="m 30,50 h 40" />
            <path class="line bottom"
                d="m 30,67 h 40 c 12.796276,0 15.357889,-11.717785 15.357889,-26.851538 0,-15.133752 -4.786586,-27.274118 -16.667516,-27.274118 -11.88093,0 -18.499247,6.994427 -18.435284,17.125656 l 0.252538,40" />
        </svg>
        <div class="top_contacts">
            <a href="https://github.com/ZMoberg" id="profile-link" class="top_contacts-link" target="_blank"
                alt="Github"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/zackmoberg/" id="profile-link" class="top_contacts-link"
                target="_blank" alt="Linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
        </div>

        <!--Navigation bar-->
        <nav id="navbar" class="nav">
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#about_scroll">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#projects-scroll">PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <span class="circle three" id="three-overflow"></span>
        <section class="head_sub">
            <h1 class="title">ZACK MOBERG</h1>
            <p class="title_sub">Web Developer & UI/UX Designer</p>
            <div class="header_nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="title_nav"><a href="#about_scroll" class="left">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li class="title_nav"><a href="#projects-scroll" class="left">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li class="title_nav"><a href="#contact" class="left">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Scroll down animation -->

        <div class="mouse_scroll">
            <a href="#about_scroll">
                <div class="mouse">
                    <div class="wheel"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="scroll_arrows">
                    <span class="m_scroll_arrows unu"></span>
                    <span class="m_scroll_arrows doi"></span>
                    <span class="m_scroll_arrows trei"></span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Bruno for taking the time to look at my issue. Unfortunately by adding overflow: hidden to the header element it restricts the span img to the landing page viewport. I want it to overflow into the next section below to create the scrolling effect of it overlapping the landing page.

Comment: Also adding overflow-x: hidden fixes the issue along the x-axis but adds a secondary scrollbar for the image as well as restricts it to the landing page's viewport.

Comment: Are you adding `overflow-x: hidden` to the body or to the header? If you want the circle to overflow into the sections below, you need to add it to body. I have edited the snippet, take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you Bruno, I was able to utilize the overflow-x: hidden property on the body. The scrolling was affected because you cannot use position: sticky with a parent element with the overflow property set. By creating a simple separate scrolling div around the elements I wanted to be affected by the sticky property.